# I need a suggestion on service I might be able to use for my application (gw->sns->sqs->lambda->redis aws service that I can access from public?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, redis, amazon-sns

Right now I have the following basic service that I spin up using aws cdk

gateway -> sns -> sqs -> lambda -> redis (heroku add on)

it basically fans-out the message that I sent to apigw (/post api endpoint)
the lambda will basically just enque the message in the redis (I still don't have a concrete idea on mind what aws service I would use)

the idea is I want to be able to fan out the message to my dev environment aswell as staging..

I had the idea for dev to just run the redis locally then use ngrok to expose this so my lambda can enque to it but I got roadblocked by ngrok assigning me different port for tcp everytime I restart the redis. I am thinking maybe there is a more reasonable and logical way I can do this.

connecting to my staging is simple because it is just running in heroku (heroku addon) which gives me a public endpoint I can just plug into my lambda.